# How to write nested conjunctions (OR and AND clauses) in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Does anybody know how to produce nested conjunctions in SQLAlchemy?

I have some Python code similar to this:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

a = sa.and_(mytable.col1 > 1, mytable.col2 < 3)
b = sa.and_(mytable.col1 < 1, mytable.col4 == None)
clause_args = [a, b] 
or_clauses = sa.or_(*clause_args)
session.query(mytable).filter(mytable.status.in_([1,2,3,4])).filter(or_clauses)
```

Note, this is just some pseudocode to demonstrate syntactical problem I am having.
Don't analyze query logic too much. I just want to find a way how to add parenthesis around AND and OR blocks.
SQLAlchemy produces SQL similar to this:

```
SELECT
     id, status, name, col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM mytable
WHERE
    status in (1,2,3,4)
AND (col1 > 1 
     AND col2 < 3
     OR col1 < 1
     AND col4 is NULL);
```

Note, AND condition has no parenthesis around logical AND blocks between ORs:

```
AND (col1 > 1 
     AND col2 < 3
     OR col1 < 1
     AND col4 is NULL);
```

I would like to force use of parenthesis in the filter with or_ and and_ conjunctions.
I would like to parenthesize conditions so that SQL output looks like this:

```
SELECT
     id, status, name, col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM mytable
WHERE
    status in (1,2,3,4)
AND ((col1 > 1 
     AND col2 < 3)
     OR (col1 < 1
     AND col4 is NULL));
```

Can anybody suggest how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154009/how-to-nest-conjunctions-or-and-and-in-sqlalchamey

Comment: OP, did you end up finidng a solution ?

Answer (score 20):

Use self_group(). Documentation Link: [self_group](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ClauseElement.self_group)

Solution for the example looks like

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

a = sa.and_(mytable.col1 > 1, mytable.col2 < 3).self_group()
b = sa.and_(mytable.col1 < 1, mytable.col4 == None).self_group()
clause_args = [a, b] 
or_clauses = sa.or_(*clause_args)
session.query(mytable).filter(mytable.status.in_([1,2,3,4])).filter(or_clauses)
```

Comment: The same documentation that your linked to, explicitly says: [the application of self_group() is automatic - end-user code should never need to use this method directly](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ClauseElement.self_group)

Comment: Self-group behavior is inconsistently applied from my experience - for instance, on SQLAlchemy 1.3.16 I can trigger the behavior by wrapping a series of `and_` blocks within an `or_` block.  Forcing behavior via `self_group()` works well to assert conditionals, no matter how the parser may tweak its own behavior in the future.  Anecdotal, but this "automatic" application caused a number of very subtle query bugs when it stopped being automatic.

Comment: @tombishop83 Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, the parentheses you are looking for are not needed since AND takes precedence over OR.

Comment: Yap -> https://www.alphacodingskills.com/postgresql/notes/postgresql-operators-precedence.php