# How to nest conjunctions or_ and and_ in SQLAlchamey

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm tyring to recreate this query in SQL Alchamey but I've been unable to nest the filters:

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM calendar 
where (recurrenceRule = '') 
or (recurrenceRule != '' and start < @end1);
```

Python:

```
events.filter(or_(Calendar.recurrenceRule!='',
      (Calendar.recurrenceRule=='',Calendar.start>=filterStart))
```

This python results in the following exception:
"SQL expression object or string expected."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `and_` explicitly:

```
events.filter(or_(
    Calendar.recurrenceRule!='',
    and_(Calendar.recurrenceRule=='', Calendar.start>=filterStart))
)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I thought the (condition,condition) notation implied an and_.